# good way for my database app RESTful hierarchy and push to array

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I use firebase with ionic (angularJS) and its my first utilisation of firebase. Im thinking about my database hierarchy and I am i bit confused.

```
myapp {
    "gyms": {
        "0": {},
        "1": {},
        "2": {}
    },
    "users" : {
        "0" : {},
        "1": {},
        "2": {}
    },
    "sessions" : {
        "0" : {
            "user_id": {
                "session_id": {
                    "routes": {
                        "0": {

                        },
                        "1": {

                        },
                        "2": {

                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "1": {},
        "2": {}
    },
}
```

What i need with RESTful :

```
// GYMS
gyms/
    GET all gym objects
    POST : I put manually a new gym with id: 0, 1, 2 ...
gyms/:gym_id
    GET the gym corresponding to the id
        exemple : gyms/0
gyms/:gym_id/users
    GET all users from a specific gym

// USERS
users/
    GET all users
    POST create a new user, i would have a user_id numeric like id 0, 1, 2...
users/:user_id
    GET the user corresponding to the id

// SESSIONS
sessions/
    GET all sessions objects
sessions/:user_id
    GET all sessions from a specific user
    POST create a new session for the user
sessions/:user_id/:session_id
    GET a specific session from a specific user
sessions/:user_id/:session_id/routes
    GET all routes from a specific session and user
    POST create a new route for the session
sessions/:user_id/:session_id/routes/:route_id
    GET a specific route from a specific session and user
```

for resume, gyms contains users who have sessions. Each sessions contains routes. Each user is associated to a gym, and each session is at a user. Each session contains some routes. First time i make a JSON database, so, it is good ?

I said higher i want id like `0, 1, 2` for having a RESTful url like   `sessions/12/4/routes/8`. But i seen the article for array and push with uniqueID generated from firebase like `"-JyNAzZHIoMEpBe39a55"` but what is the function for pushing an object to an array and have a id like 0, 1, 2? Because url like `sessions/JyNAzZHIoMEpBe39a55/JyNAzZHIoMEpBe39a57/routes/JyNAzZHIoMEpBe39a57` are less human readable no ?

sorry for my bad english !

Answer (score 0):

Sequential indices may be more readable. Whether they are better, depends on your aims. Firebase was designed for highly scalable multi-user systems, where indices are likely to become a bottleneck as users are adding items to the database.

From the Firebase [blog post on our push ids](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html):

> We created push IDs for collaborative, multi-user applications to handle situations where many clients are adding to a list at the same time. We needed IDs that could be generated client-side so that they wouldn’t need to wait for a round-trip to the server. And we needed them to be unique so that many clients could append data to the same location at the same time without worrying about conflicts.

You're free to come up with your own scheme of course, but this summarizes why Firebase recommends using push ids.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand this point, in my case i dont have manu clients posting at the same time, so i can bypassing push ID to use numeric ID for more human readable ID. But i dont know how i can push a new user to my /users with a numeric ID. Is there another function than push() for numeric ID ? Maybe i have missed something, im new to JSON database.